# Socket.IO ping without client-side script

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I have an Android application and when somebody forces it to stop it doesn't fire the disconnect event on the server side.

Since I can't force people to update their android app, I can't make a ping event handler on the client side.
How could I check on the server side whether the client is active without client-side modification?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out why the disconnect event doesn't fire.
Have you put the socket's disconnect event **inside** the `connection` callback?
Also pay attention to variable *io* and *socket*. Maybe you put it wrong.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('user connected');

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
```

If the structure is already right, then I believe you should check the client's code.